# Netplan DNS not working

Tags: networking, server, dns, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to setup a bridge interface to use with KVM guests. I can successfully SSH to other computers on the same network. I can also `ping 8.8.8.8` directly. However, when I try to `ping google.com` I get: `ping: google.com: Name or service not known`. So it seems like routing, etc. is working fine, but `DNS` is not. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my current netplan config:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: yes
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [enp2s0]
      addresses: [10.0.0.20/24]
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 10.0.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
        search: []
      parameters:
        stp: false
        forward-delay: 0
      dhcp4: no
```

I don't see anything too interesting in `sudo netplan --debug apply`. Here is the output:

```
** (generate:7576): DEBUG: 16:06:02.092: starting new processing pass
** (generate:7576): DEBUG: 16:06:02.092: br0: adding new route
** (generate:7576): DEBUG: 16:06:02.092: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (generate:7576): DEBUG: 16:06:02.092: enp2s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:7576): DEBUG: 16:06:02.092: Configuration is valid
** (generate:7576): DEBUG: 16:06:02.092: br0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:7576): DEBUG: 16:06:02.092: Configuration is valid
** (generate:7576): DEBUG: 16:06:02.093: Generating output files..
** (generate:7576): DEBUG: 16:06:02.093: openvswitch: definition enp2s0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:7576): DEBUG: 16:06:02.093: NetworkManager: definition enp2s0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:7576): DEBUG: 16:06:02.093: openvswitch: definition br0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:7576): DEBUG: 16:06:02.093: NetworkManager: definition br0 is not for us (backend 1)
(generate:7576): GLib-DEBUG: 16:06:02.093: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested)
(generate:7576): GLib-DEBUG: 16:06:02.096: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested)
DEBUG:netplan generated networkd configuration changed, reloading networkd
DEBUG:enp2s0 not found in {}
DEBUG:br0 not found in {}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  bridges:
    br0:
      addresses:
      - 10.0.0.20/24
      dhcp4: false
      interfaces:
      - enp2s0
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
        search: []
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: false
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 10.0.0.1
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: true
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2

DEBUG:no netplan generated NM configuration exists
DEBUG:enp2s0 not found in {}
DEBUG:br0 not found in {}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  bridges:
    br0:
      addresses:
      - 10.0.0.20/24
      dhcp4: false
      interfaces:
      - enp2s0
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
        search: []
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: false
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 10.0.0.1
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: true
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2

DEBUG:Link changes: {}
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for enp2s0
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for br0
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for vnet0
** (process:7574): DEBUG: 16:06:02.790: starting new processing pass
** (process:7574): DEBUG: 16:06:02.790: br0: adding new route
** (process:7574): DEBUG: 16:06:02.790: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (process:7574): DEBUG: 16:06:02.791: enp2s0: setting default backend to 1
** (process:7574): DEBUG: 16:06:02.791: Configuration is valid
** (process:7574): DEBUG: 16:06:02.791: br0: setting default backend to 1
** (process:7574): DEBUG: 16:06:02.791: Configuration is valid
DEBUG:enp2s0 not found in {}
DEBUG:br0 not found in {}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  bridges:
    br0:
      addresses:
      - 10.0.0.20/24
      dhcp4: false
      interfaces:
      - enp2s0
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
        search: []
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: false
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 10.0.0.1
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: true
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2
```

Comment: I read your error as ping is not found. Have you tried to ping any other site?

Comment: Does `sudo netplan --debug apply` give you anything interesting?

Comment: @David any time I try to ping a hostname I get the error. But if I ping the IP address directly ping works fine. This is why I'm thinking the issue is isolated to DNS.

Comment: @Jos unfortunately no. `sudo netplan --debug apply` looks normal as far as I can tell. I'll add the output to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is truly an answer, but I did manage to fix my problem so I'll at least close this out. This was a new server setup anyway, so I just re-installed Ubuntu and started from scratch and for some reason it's working now, so not sure what exactly I did to fix it. But for reference, here is the final netplan config that I ended up with:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [enp2s0]
      addresses: [10.0.0.20/24]
      gateway4: 10.0.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
      parameters:
        stp: false
        forward-delay: 0
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
```